# How to know if an an array contains only a particular value for all the elements

Tags: arrays, javacard

How can I more elegantly tell if a ***JavaCard*** byte array contains only a particular element as shown in the example below:

```
{(byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xAA}
```

I am trying not to write loops and if-else to search through the entire array and match if it contains just a particular element (0xAA for this example above). Is there some sort of method to do it ?

Comment: You mean like using a lookup table?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to implement a lookup array. I want to know if the entire array is filled with a specific particular element or not.

Comment: Ok. Check my answer.

Comment: -1 For the fact that you know you're working on a confined platform and  should know that the most **elegant** way, library or not, will still be done using a loop.

Comment: @chx101 I find your downvoting quite unfair and it seems to be motivated by the fact that your answer was not accepted. Java Card is a very complicated platform and no, the easiest solution (loop) is not often the best one. Java Card proprietary libraries (and specific implementations of Java Card libraries) often provide hardware-specific low-level instructions you cannot use from your code directly. Java Card is not Java.

Comment: To put it straight, chx101, I am not the one to -1 on your post and in fact I decided to bold and italic my original post (in case i weren't clear enough originally) when I noticed your answers are not matching my question to give you time to re-think or withdraw. My open question to the community for a more efficient way to check elements in an array in a constrained environment is precisely what vojta voiced as I am only working on a 2KB RAM and 16 bit processor smart card and have very little RAM space left and I need a solution to reduce loops, speed things up and efficiently handle RAM.

Comment: @thotheolh Is your problem solved? Should I add some information? Please, update us with some info, or accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Java Card is a very limited platform with almost no fancy libraries. A loop and if-else/break is generally the best thing you can do and it there is nothing wrong about doing so.

---

If your array had a fixed (or limited) size, you might create a RAM buffer and use `Util` class and its static methods to fill it with your byte value and then compare the whole array in one piece:

```
private final byte[] temp = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(SIZE_LIMIT, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
private final boolean containsSameValues(final byte[] arr, final byte value)
{
    if (arr.length > SIZE_LIMIT) {
         //throw some error code...
    }
    Util.fillArrayNonAtomic(temp, (short) 0, (short) arr.length, value);
    return Util.arrayCompare(arr, (short) 0, temp, (short) 0, (short) arr.length) == 0;
}
```

However, this solution might be even slower than a common loop. Everything depends on your hardware and your Java Card implementation.

Comment: If there is only a limited number of searched for patterns (as in case of e.g. checking the correct padding), it _might_ make sense to prepare all the arrays in advance during the applet installation (in the persistent memory as it is really cheap) an then just call the `Util.arrayCompare()`.

Comment: And love the idea that if the tested array's size has some upper bound, you can use that long reference array and check only the actual length of the tested array (would emphasize it a bit more in the answer) -- using that myself for zero padding check (even in C).